# Type of an ArrayList for Combobox and TextFields

Tags: java, swing, polymorphism, jtextfield, jcombobox

I have an `ArrayList<JTextField>` that has N positions. However, I have to make a change, I need to add a `JComboBox` to that array so my question is:

What type of data do I need to declare on my ArrayList?

I've tryed with an `ArrayList<Object>` and `ArrayList<JComponent>` but it doesn't work because the lines, where I set the horizontal alignment report errors.

```
private ArrayList<JTextField> jTextFieldAL;

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            jLabelAL.add(new JLabel("" + tagNamesAL.get(i))); 
            if (tagNamesAL.get(i).equals("AGENT_NAME")) {
                jTextFieldAL.add(new tools.AgentNameTextField());
                jTextFieldAL.get(i).setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
            } else {
                switch (tagContentAL.get(i).toString().toLowerCase()) { 
                    case "int":
                        jTextFieldAL.add(new tools.IntegerTextField(this.simul));
                        jTextFieldAL.get(i).setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
                        break;                                                    
                    case "double":
                    case "float":
                        jTextFieldAL.add(new tools.DoubleTextField(this.simul)); 
                        jTextFieldAL.get(i).setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
                        break;
                    default:
                        jTextFieldAL.add(new JTextField()); 
                        jTextFieldAL.get(i).setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
                        break;
                } 
            }

            jTextFieldAL.get(i).addKeyListener(keyEvent); 
            p1.add(jLabelAL.get(i));
            p1.add(jTextFieldAL.get(i));
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried using JComponent but casting to e.g. JTextField if you need to use a text-specific method?

Comment: 1. simple question - whats goal, 2. how can help you to put JComponents to array, 3. don't to use KeyListener for JTextComponents, 4. for better help sooner post an  [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable,

Comment: sorry mKorbel, I really can't :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution to my problem. I don't need to add the `ComboBox` to the ArrayList. I just add the `ComboBox` directy to the panel.

Like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            jLabelAL.add(new JLabel("" + tagNamesAL.get(i))); 
            if (tagNamesAL.get(i).equals("BEHAVIOUR")){
                addCSPComboBox(p1);
                break;
            }
```

And the addCSPComboBox method:

```
public void addCSPComboBox(JPanel p1){
    CSPComboBox cspComboBox = new tools.CSPComboBox();
    JLabel behaviour = new JLabel("BEHAVIOUR");
    p1.add(behaviour);
    p1.add(cspComboBox);

}
```

This works just fine for my problem. I hope I can help anyone with the same problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've tryed with an ArrayList and ArrayList but it doesn't work because the lines, where I set the horizontal alignment report errors : this is expected because Object/JComponent does not have setHorizontalAlignment method.
So you need to down caste it to JTextField and than call this API.

I am not sure if this is a good idea to use, as to down caste the object, you need to know at each index what type is the actual type of the object stored(JTextFild or JComboBox), otherwise you will land up with ClassCasteException.